How to set DBCP ConnectionPool in processor PutDatabaseRecord in Nifi to put data in a docker Postgres
let me start by saying that I'm a newcomer to NiFi and databases, so the questions I'm about to ask come after various searches that haven't led to anything:
So, I have a Kubernetes platform on which I've installed a PostgreSQL Docker container with a database. I've already set up a workflow on NiFi that works like this:
ListenHttp --> content routes --> publishkafka,`
and so far everything is working fine. Then I added another rule to routeOncontent to send these JSON files to my PostgreSQL database using putDatabaseRecord, but it rightly asks me to enable a DBCP.
I did it, but it keeps telling me it can't find the drivers. I've searched but I haven't found how to download these drivers, and specifically where to place the downloaded jar file because everyone puts it in a local NiFi folder. However, since I have NiFi as a service, I can't find this folder in the Kubernetes cluster to place the drivers.
Do you have any suggestions?
`[nifi-Workflow](https://i.sstatic.net/pJLwSFfg.png)
[putdbrecord](https://i.sstatic.net/Jp83l142.png)
[dbpc](https://i.sstatic.net/8O4QiXTK.png)
[PG Svc](https://i.sstatic.net/Bd9kl1zu.png)
`

